# Wamp and Xampp "Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress."

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, xampp, wamp

I'm trying to run Wordpress locally on Windows.

I've tried with both Xampp and Wamp and get the same error message every time I try to access my site: "Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress."

I've tried many solutions from the web, none of them work. The two most common are:

- uncomment "extension=php_mysqli.dll" in php.ini: that line was not even present in xampp or wamp, I added it but no change.
- make sure extension_dir="C:\xampp\php\ext" is set up correctly in php.ini : I made sure of that and no luck.

What can I try now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I just found a solution that works for me: in wamp, click on the icon -> php -> version -> 5.6